# LINQ query with multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have 1 main table and 3 tables for ordering the fields in the main table. I return all these tables as lists.

The main table structure is like this:

| Color | Make | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Black | Mercedes | Germany |
| Blue | Mercedes | Germany |
| Cyan | Mercedes | Germany |
| Red | Mercedes | Germany |
| Blue | BMW | Germany |
| Red | BMW | Germany |
| Blue | Toyota | Japan |
| Purple | Mercedes | Germany |

And The Ordering tables have Field Names in the main table and another numeric field for their ordering number, an example :

| Color | ColorOrder |
| --- | --- |
| Black | 6 |
| Blue | 2 |
| Cyan | 3 |
| Red | 4 |

Now I want to order the Main table based on ordering numbers in Ordering Tables in LINQ. In case on the main table if there is no corresponding field in the ordering table then the ordering number should be 0 (In ColorOrdering there is no Purple For example)

Just to be concrete I have made a working sample in Access and Query is as below:

```
SELECT Cars.Color, Cars.Make, Cars.Country,
IIf([MakeOrder] Is Null,0,[MakeOrder]) AS MkOrder,
IIf([ColorOrder] Is Null,0,[ColorOrder]) AS ClOrder,
IIf([CountryOrder] Is Null,0,[CountryOrder]) AS CntOrder
FROM ((Cars LEFT JOIN ColorOrder ON Cars.Color = ColorOrder.Color) 
LEFT JOIN MakeOrder ON Cars.Make = MakeOrder.Make) 
LEFT JOIN CountryOrder ON Cars.Country = CountryOrder.Country
ORDER BY 
IIf([MakeOrder] Is Null,0,[MakeOrder]),
IIf([ColorOrder] Is Null,0,[ColorOrder]), 
IIf([CountryOrder] Is Null,0,[CountryOrder]);
```

My problem is one of the ordering tables has no records (Country Table). So when I make a join to that table, whatever I do I keep getting,

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' cntord was null.

Here is my LINQ Query, help on this is much appreciated.

```cs
List<CarsWithOrdering> carsWithOrdering = (from c in Cars
//Also tried this, doesn't work
//join cntord in CountryOrderingList.DefaultIfEmpty()
// on c.Country equals cntord.Country
join cntord in CountryOrderingList
on c.Country equals cntord.Country into lcntord
from cntord in lcntord.DefaultIfEmpty()
//........ (Other 2 left joins similar to above one)
select new CarsWithOrdering
{
    Color = c.Color,
    Make = c.Make,
    Country = c.Country,        
    ColorOrder = int.Parse(colord.ItemValue) ?? 0,
    MakeOrder = int.Parse(makord.ItemValue) ?? 0,
    CountryOrder = int.Parse(cntord.ItemValue) ?? 0
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to check whether the LEFT JOIN Table is null or not before accessing its properties. For example: `cntord != null ? int.Parse(cntord.ItemValue) : 0`. Same goes for other LEFT JOIN table(s).

Comment: Hello, Thanks this solved the issue, if you can make it as an answer I can mark it  as the answer so others can also benefit

Comment: Well, there more to this. How do you get the results from the database into a LINQ query? If this is through some ORM like Entity Framework, you should get rid of these joins altogether and use navigation properties.

Comment: Hi, no those lists are being imported from Excel into memory not from DataBase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-5.0)

```cs
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue);
```

> Returns
>
> IEnumerable An IEnumerable that contains defaultValue if source is empty; otherwise, source.

`.DefaultIfEmpty()` will return `null` when the list is empty.

---

**Solution**

Hence, you **need to do `null` checking** for the LEFT JOIN table's value before accessing its properties.

```cs
List<CarsWithOrdering> carsWithOrdering = (from c in Cars
    join cntord in CountryOrderingList
    on c.Country equals cntord.Country into lcntord
    from cntord in lcntord.DefaultIfEmpty()
    //Other LEFT JOIN tables
    select new CarsWithOrdering
    {
        Color = c.Color,
        Make = c.Make,
        Country = c.Country,        
        ColorOrder = colord != null ? int.Parse(colord.ItemValue) : 0,
        MakeOrder = makord != null ? int.Parse(makord.ItemValue) : 0,
        CountryOrder = cntord != null ? int.Parse(cntord.ItemValue) : 0
    })
    .ToList();
```